# QAF: '401 Unauthorized: Access is denied' when running script with NTLM request

Tags: java, json, api, ntlm, qaf

I already implemented the NTLMAuthClient class

> rest.client.impl=com.qmetry.qaf.automation.ws.client.NTLMAuthClient

into the project properties but still getting the aforementioned error.

Here is the JSON request template I am using and I am not sure whether the structure is what causes the error:

```
{
    "headers":
    {
        "Authorization":
        [
            {
                "username": "${ntlm.user}",
                "password": "${ntlm.password}"
            },
            {
                "domain": "${ntlm.domain}"
            }
        ],
        "Content-Type":"application/json"
    },
    
    "endPoint": "",
    "baseUrl": "${base_url}/api/data/v4/contacts(integrationkey='${clientNumber}')",
    "method": "PATCH",
    
    "body":
    {
        "userid": ""
    }
}
```

And here's the response from the QMetry report:

**Request**

> Client out-bound request  PATCH
> [https://xxxx.com/CRMDEV2/api/data/v4/contacts(integrationkey='xxxx')](https://xxxx.com/CRMDEV2/api/data/v4/contacts(integrationkey=%27xxxx%27))
> Authorization: [{username=xxxx, password=xxxx},
> {domain=xxxx}]  Content-Type: application/json
> {"userid":""}

**Reponse**

> Client in-bound response 401 REQ_ID:
> 3d391170-40d7-4ea6-80ca-2531a7fe73ff Server: WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
> WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate Set-Cookie:
> ReqClientId=21490c2c-bdfe-4c00-9330-401ca0bb5811; expires=Thu,
> 22-Oct-2071 11:59:11 GMT; path=/; secure; HttpOnly Content-Length: 49
> Date: Fri, 22 Oct 2021 11:59:11 GMT Content-Type: text/plain HTTP
> Error 401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied

Appreciate the help.

**QAF and Selenium version I am using:**

> QAF version: 2.1.14
>
> Selenium: 3.141.59

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer [NTLMAuthClient java-doc](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.qmetry/qaf-support-ws/3.0.1/com/qmetry/qaf/automation/ws/client/NTLMAuthClient.html). Instead of Authorization in request call header, you should try providing properties used by `NTLMAuthClient`.

`NTLMAuthClient` class uses following properties:

```
ntlm.user - The user name. This should not include the domain to authenticate with. For example: "user" is correct whereas "DOMAIN\\user" is not.
ntlm.password - The password
ntlm.workstation - workstation (default is blank) The workstation the authentication request is originating from. Essentially, the computer name for this machine.
ntlm.domain- domain The domain to authenticate within (default is blank). 
#register NTLMAuthClient
rest.client.impl=com.qmetry.qaf.automation.ws.client.NTLMAuthClient
```

set above properties in your property file and then try **without** authorization in request call header.

Comment: Thanks. I have followed your answer but I am still getting the same error. Was thinking my project has an outdated qaf-support-ws version -- currently at 2.1.13.